# Getting the msgbus for a Color Palette

Tags: python

I'm trying to follow the example from this post on Blender Stack Exchange:
[Example of persistent usage of «bpy.msgbus» and how to manage it?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166469/example-of-persistent-usage-of-bpy-msgbus-and-how-to-manage-it)

I want to catch the event when a color has been added to a Palette. I have tried
`subscribe_to = bpy.types.Palette, "colors"` and `subscribe_to = bpy.context.tool_settings.image_paint.palette.path_resolve("colors", False)`, but neither has worked. Can anyone please advise how I may detect when a Palette's colors have changed? Thank you!

```py
    subscribe_to = bpy.types.Palette, "colors"

    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=subscribe_to,
        owner=subscription_owner,
        args=("a", "b", "c"),
        notify=notification_handler,
        options={"PERSISTENT",}
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @HarryMcKenzie. Sure thing (In Texture Paint Mode: Tool > Brush Settings > Color Palette Panel:
https://snipboard.io/SFsQkG.jpg

Comment: According to this link, https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/message-bus/, the Message Bus doesn't work with changes in the Viewport, which is how I was creating Colors (Sampling colors with Alt+ S + Left Click).

If anyone knows of an alternate way to listen to this change, I'd appreciate learning it! The article says message bus DOES work with changes in the Python API, so `bpy.context.tool_settings.image_paint.palette.colors` should work.

Comment: take note the msgbus capability is very limited. it might not be possible.

Comment: i did some more digging and it seems like it's really not supported if not a bug. maybe file a bug report.

Comment: I REALLY appreciate that @HarryMcKenzie. Thank you! I will file a bug report.

Comment: Oops, too late: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/110383

Comment: haha no worries. but i would keep ur bug report simple with a simple code example because the other part is not relevant